# HeifWriter support library min API level is 28

Tags: android, android-support-library, heif

High i'm new in android development and trying to use HeifWriter support library for my project. How I understand support libraries are for supporting lower api levels with new features but heifwriter min sdk is api 28. And i can't understand why i can't use HeifWriter in lower api levels or why it is in support library

Comment: What can't you understand here? HeifWriter requires min api 28 and it's not backward compatible.

Comment: @user1209216 why it is in support library?

Comment: @VladBadalyan Is in the support library so bug fixes and new functionalities can be easily implemented without depending on Android OS updates.